# Dart Function.appy() does not work on Color.fromARGB(a, r, g, b);

Tags: constructor, dart, flutter

Experimenting with Function.apply() to pass a list of positional parameters. But why doesn't a constructor method work for class Color?

```
var x = Function.apply(Color.fromARGB, [255, 66, 165, 245]);

Error Message: The getter 'fromARGB' isn't defined for the class 'Color'.
```

Here is the constructor.

```
const Color.fromARGB(int a, int r, int g, int b) :
  value = (((a & 0xff) << 24) |
           ((r & 0xff) << 16) |
           ((g & 0xff) << 8)  |
           ((b & 0xff) << 0)) & 0xFFFFFFFF;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A named constructor is not a `Function` in Dart.

The current way to write your sample is:

```
var x = Function.apply(
    (int a, int r, int g, int b) => Color.fromARGB(a, r, g, b),
    [255, 66, 165, 245]);
```

https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/216 is the canonical issue to track requesting support for "tearing off" a constructor to treat it as a `Function`.